# Max lines with height set as wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

I have two TextViews in a vertical LinearLayout, one serves as a display for a book's title and the latter as a display for the book's author(s).
I need the first to have wrap_content as its height, so it takes a good part of the linear layout. However, I want it to cap out at three lines max, so that there is still some space left for the second text view;
and I need the latter to fill the remaining space (0dp and layout_weight=0dp).
I want to use specific configuration so that the author view will be always right after the title view (on its bottom).

[image]

Something like this, however the max_lines do not kick in.

I tried to set max_lines to 3 and wrap_content for the first view height, but it seem that max_lines is ignored if height is set to wrap_content.

I also tried to circumvent the problem by sort of cheating and adding a max_height, but then the two views may be spaced apart from one another.

At last I tried to convert the linear layout to a constraint layout, to see if I could access some other layout settings to no avail.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing app:max_lines with android:max_lines seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working fine on my side with `android:max_lines="3"` even with `wrap_content`

This is just a test layout I created

```xml
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Long Text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Very Very Short Text "
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textview1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview1" />
```

**Screenshot ->**

[image: Device Screenshot]

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that I used app:max_lines instead of android:max_lines which apparently has a different behaviour.
Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Glad it got solved :)